# In Scala dataframe, consolidate equivalent rows after pairwise comparison

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in scala that is the result of a pairwise comparison between all rows in the original data against itself along with a score. I'm looking for an efficient way to consolidate the two rows that result from each pair (e.g. Value1, Value2 and Value2, Value1).

If it is relevant, this dataframe is created from a spark.read.table command referencing the table that holds all these rows. My first thought was a loop that basically built a new dataframe and checked each row to see if we've already stored that pair in the new one, but I was hoping there was a more scala-y way that would accomplish it much more efficiently.

Optimally, I would be looking at a subset of values within a score range, and consolidating multiple rows into the "first" one (where "first" can just be first alphabetically).

Data

```
Item1     Item2     1.5
Item2     Item1     1.5
Item3     Item4     2.6
Item4     Item3     2.6
Item3     Item5     2.7
Item5     Item3     2.7
```

Result

```
Item1     Item2     1.5
Item3     Item4     2.6
Item3     Item5     2.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So working from the idea from Vamsi, here's the scala version (since the question was about scala, not pyspark).

```
val df = spark.read.table("table_name")
  .withColumn("NewNameA", least('nameA, 'nameB))
  .withColumn("NewNameB", greatest('nameA,'nameB))
  .dropDuplicates("NewNameA","NewNameB")
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the inbuilt `least` and `greatest` functions. Example with PySpark shown here.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(f.least(df.col1,df.col2).alias('i1'),
          f.greatest(df.col1,df.col2).alias('i2'),
          df.price
         ).distinct()
```

`greatest` returns the greatest value from amongst the columns selected while `least` selects the lowest value amongst them.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. If you can updated it to have a scala example instead/in addition to, I will accept the answer. I put what I put together in an additional answer.